# Do Google Workspace Add-ons support drag and drop?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm creating a Google Calendar add-on and I was wondering if I could implement drag and drop support, to drag an event from my add-on to the calendar.

The Google Tasks add-on supports it (you can drag and drop tasks onto the calendar), but it's unclear whether it's using public or private APIs to achieve it.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by `to drag an event from my add-on to the calendar`. Where is the event coming from, when was it created? What's the purpose of dragging it to the calendar? Can you provide more information, maybe including some screenshot, to understand your purpose?

Comment: Here's the functionality I'm trying to reproduce with my add-on: https://imgur.com/a/R06pTSU

Comment: My add-on contains a list of event templates (e.g., "1-hour workout"). I want to let the user drag and drop an event template on the calendar to materialize an actual Google Calendar event with the corresponding summary and duration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Calendar add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar) (or for that matter, any [Workspace add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-gsuite-addons)) don't provide this kind of functionality. Add-ons sidebars are based on [Cards](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/card-interfaces), and these don't contain any element that can be dragged outside the card-based interface (see [class CardService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service) for a reference of what you can do with cards).

#### File a feature request:

If you want to see this implemented, I'd suggest filing a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206).